Clarification of a proof
The Lemma 4.2 in the paper
Deruelle, Alix, Steady gradient Ricci soliton with curvature in (L^1), Commun. Anal. Geom. 20, No. 1, 31-54 (2012). ZBL1244.53053.
is given by

I am not able to understand the line marked red. How is it possible to find a subsequence $r_k\rightarrow +\infty$ such that the sequence $\{A(p,r_k )\}$ is bounded? Please give some suggestions on how this conclusion comes.

What is the volume growth assumption?

The assumption $Vol (B(p,r))\leq c_pr$ is called the volume growth assumption.

Have you thought about using $\int_0^rA(p,s)ds\geq r\cdot\inf_{s\in[0,r]}A(p,s)$?

But $inf_{s\in[0,r]}A(p,s)=A(p,0)=0$

Note that the inequality holds only for $r\ge 1$,  so starting at $r=0$ isn't a good idea.

@TedShifrin. Yes sir.  Sir, can you please explain how such kind of sequence exists?

If not, then there is $r_0$ so that $A(p,r)\ge 2c_p$ for all $r\ge r_0$. Now what?

I got it. Thank you sir

You're welcome. Why don't you write up an answer?

Thank you @Ted Shifrin. Inspiring by your idea, here is the proof:
Suppose there exists $r_0$ such that $A(p,r)\geq 2c_p$. Then,
$\int_0^{r_0}A(p,r)ds=Vol(B(p,r_0))\geq 2c_pr_0>c_0r_0.$
